# Connection closed while receiving data, uri = '${https-img-url-from-gcp}.png' Error in firebase crashlytics

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm getting a lot of non-fatal logs in Firebase Crashlytics saying connection closed while receiving data. But I'm not able to reproduce the same issue using an emulator. Any ideas why this is happening? Below is the error logged in Firebase Crashlytics.

flutter_error_reason
thrown HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, uri = https://storage.googleapis.com/prod/uploads/catImage.png. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'.